# How do I replace the last output in the console with another output?

Tags: java, windows

I'm working on Windows, and I want to be able to output multiple lines **over** the last output (which may as well contain multiple lines).
How do I do this?

For example:
 A simple menu will pop up like

> 1. alphabet
> 2. numbers

The user inputs 1

Output:

**a

b

c

d

e**

Then the user inputs 2 again

I would want the console to erase the last blocks of output and replace them with the new output.

so

**a

b

c

d

e**

will be replaced by

**1

2

3

4**

in the console (they don't have the same number of lines.)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You'd probably want to use a library that supports vt100 terminally output.

Comment: pls add the expected output as well

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test3{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException,InterruptedException{
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = -2;
        int prevInput = -2;
        while(input != -1){
            System.out.println("\nMenu");
            System.out.println("---------");
            System.out.println("1: Alphabet");
            System.out.println("2: Numbers");
            System.out.print("Enter input : ");
            input = sc.nextInt();
            if(input!=prevInput)
                new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "cls").inheritIO().start().waitFor();
            if(input == 1)
                System.out.println("a\nb\nc\nd\ne\n");
            else 
                System.out.println("1\n2\n3\n4");
            prevInput = input;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a more simpler solution than this? I'm fairly new so this is kind of a bit advanced for me.

Comment: Try the old school style then:

        System.out.println("1");
        System.out.println("\n".repeat(80));
        System.out.println("2");

What it basically do is print blank lines until the above lines disappear. This is how some consoles still work.

Comment: I want to  be able to see the menu still (where the choices are displayed) no matter how many outputs?

Comment: @Iwasamistake See Edited Code. All you need to do is put the menu into the loop